# Table with number but without caption

Tags: tables

Is there a way to add a table with a table-number shown below it, but without any caption?

I also need to add a label for referencing the table.

When I use `\caption{}`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
1
&
2
\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{}\label{lab}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The tabled is numbered but it has `:` after the number as if there is some caption after it.

[image]

Comment: `\caption{} ` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. Yes. I don't want to add any comment for the table. But I need it be numbered and referenced.

Comment: oh you don't even want the number printed? just be able to reference it with `\ref` ? No you say you do want the number printed. `\caption{}` will produce something like `Table 3`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That would take me quite a long time to find.

Comment: @Johannes_B the power of hyperref....

Comment: @user62181 I think you need to clarify your question to distinguish "without any caption" which you say you want from "an empty caption" as produced by `\caption{}` if you say that is not what you want.

Comment: I was thinking of a printed book. A little yellow post-it sticking out of the block might do :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `\caption{}` to a table adds an unwanted table separator to the caption.  For example, you might end up with a caption:

```
Table 1:
```

You can control this, for example, with the package `caption`.  For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[labelsep=none]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \toprule
    left number & right number \\
    \midrule
     5.6 &  3.8 \\
     1.3 & 20.4 \\
    10.4 &  5.2 \\
     1.3 &  0.8 \\
     7.2 &  3.9 \\
     2.5 & 16.2 \\
     \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{}
  \label{tab:tab}
\end{table}

Let's refer to Table~\ref{tab:tab}.

\end{document}
```

The caption now reads:

```
Table 1
```

If there are other tables that need an ordinary caption, you can use `\captionsetup` to temporarily change options.  See the [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf) for more details.

The package also contains further options to control the caption.  For example, if you really want only the number (without "Table" in front) under the table, you can use:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[labelsep=none,labelformat=empty]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \toprule
    left number & right number \\
    \midrule
     5.6 &  3.8 \\
     1.3 & 20.4 \\
    10.4 &  5.2 \\
     1.3 &  0.8 \\
     7.2 &  3.9 \\
     2.5 & 16.2 \\
     \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{\ref{tab:tab}}
  \label{tab:tab}
\end{table}

Let's refer to table~\ref{tab:tab}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: For reference: One can also perform the caption setup locally; within the `table` environment, if need be.

Answer (score 2):

How about a `\fakecaption` that increments the table counter and sets `\tablename\ \thetable:` ? This way the label and references work.

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcommand{\fakecaption}{%
  \vskip0.5\baselineskip
  \refstepcounter{table}%
  \tablename\ \thetable%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}



\begin{document}

\blindtext[5]

In Table \ref{lab} we see important stuff!

\blindtext[5]


\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
1
&
2
\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\fakecaption\label{lab}
\end{table}

\blindtext[5]

\end{document}
```